# yaourt curl error: Couldn't connect to server

Tags: arch-linux, yaourt

I'm trying to install some packages with `yaourt`.

For example, when I try to install Google Chrome, I get the following error:

```
$ yaourt google-chrome
curl error: Couldn't connect to server
```

I can access to http://aur.archlinux.org but the command fails.

Comment: Have you tried both http://yaourt.org and AURURL="https://aur.archlinux.org"? Modify AURURL in /etc/yaourtrc

Comment: yes `https://aur.archlinux.org` is the default with `http://yaourt.org` like you suggest dont work

Comment: @warl0ck can recommend another package to package and install from AUR

Answer (score 2):

1. Ping http://aur.archlinux.org

output:
PING aur.archlinux.org (78.46.78.247) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from alderaan.archlinux.org (78.46.78.247): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=373 ms

1. Edit your hosts file(linux /etc/hosts), add "78.46.78.247 aur.archlinux.org"

Problem solved!

Comment: do you know why works with this way?

Comment: some new linux kernel

Comment: Sorry, Maybe new linux kernel ipv6 problem, so use hosts file to direct to the correct ipv4 address ;)

Comment: I have tried disabling ipv6 and it seems that everything works

Answer (score 0):

yes it is the solution, same problem in manjaro in jul 2014
https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=15097.0

I did Ping http://aur.archlinux.org
and result other ip

Edit my hosts file `/etc/hosts` in linux, add `5.9.250.164  aur.archlinux.org`
and the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

please note that the IP changed from 78.46.78.247 to 5.9.250.164.

So if you're having problems check if you have an entry in your /etc/hosts pointing to the old IP.

If your DNS is working correctly you shouldn't have to add that entry to the file anyways.